Analog speedometer with QML shader
I am trying to develop an analog speedometer in QML using a ShaderEffect, but I have not been able to achieve the expected result.
The goal is for the fill shader (a red arc image, referred to as the colorSource) to start at approximately 240 degrees on a circular reference, and end at around 320 degrees. The arc image should progress and fill the circle in place of the needle based on the RPM value. However, I have encountered difficulties in calculating the correct start and end angles.
meter.qml:
Item {
    id: rpmFillRough

    width: 536
    height: 536
    layer.enabled: true

    anchors.centerIn: parent

    layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
        readonly property real degrees: Math.PI / 180 // used for deg -> rad translations
        readonly property var colorSource: rpmFill
        readonly property var unfilledMarksSource: rpmMarksUnfilled
        readonly property var filledMarksSource: rpmMarksFilled
        property real normalizedValue: (rpm <= 10000 ? root.rpm : 10000) / 10000

        readonly property real rotDeg: 215 + (-35 - 215) * normalizedValue

        readonly property real rotRad: rotDeg * degrees
        readonly property real startCutAngleRad: rotRad - 0.5 * degrees
        readonly property real endCutAngleRad: (215 - 360 + 10) * degrees
        readonly property real textureSizePx: rpmFill.width
        readonly property real startCutRadius: 0.40
        // rotRad is negative because it's a right-handed coord system
        readonly property real s: Math.sin(-rotRad)
        readonly property real c: Math.cos(-rotRad)
        readonly property bool fillVisible: root.rpm > 1
        fragmentShader: Shader.path("tachometerShader")
    }
}

t.frag:
uniform lowp sampler2D colorSource;
uniform lowp sampler2D unfilledMarksSource;
uniform lowp sampler2D filledMarksSource;
varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
uniform lowp float s;
uniform lowp float c;
uniform lowp float startCutRadius;
uniform lowp float textureSizePx;
uniform lowp float startCutAngleRad;
uniform lowp float endCutAngleRad;
uniform lowp float rotRad;
uniform bool fillVisible;

lowp float atanApprox(lowp float y, lowp float x) {
    lowp float absX = abs(x);
    lowp float absY = abs(y);
    lowp float a = min(absX, absY) / max(absX, absY);
    lowp float s = pow(a, 2.0);
    lowp float r = ((-0.0464964749 * s + 0.15931422) * s - 0.327622764) * s * a + a;
    if (absY > absX)
        r = 1.57079637 - r;
    if (x < 0.0)
        r = 3.14159274 - r;
    if (y < 0.0)
        r = -r;
    return r;
}

void main() {
    // background
    gl_FragColor        = texture2D(unfilledMarksSource, qt_TexCoord0);

    if (!fillVisible) {
        return;
    }

    lowp vec2 srcCoord11 = vec2(
                qt_TexCoord0.x * 2. - 1.,
                1. - qt_TexCoord0.y * 2.
                );
    //            (0,0)---+              +-----(1,1)
    //   convert    |     |   ---->      | (0,0) |
    //              +---(1,1)         (-1,-1)----+
    // From OpenGL to school math coordinates; invert Y

    // get polar coordinates of the current pixel
    lowp float curAngle = atanApprox(srcCoord11.y, srcCoord11.x);
    lowp float curRadius = sqrt(srcCoord11.x * srcCoord11.x + srcCoord11.y * srcCoord11.y) + 0.05;

    // make bottom-left quadrant compatible with all others
    if(curAngle < -2.) {
        curAngle += 1.28;
    }

    // cut out what's not needed
    if(curAngle > startCutAngleRad
            && curRadius < 1.0
            && curRadius > startCutRadius
            && fillVisible) {
        lowp mat2 rotationMatrix2x2 = mat2(c, -s,  s, c);
        lowp vec2 destCoord = srcCoord11 * rotationMatrix2x2;

        // convert to back to 0..1 system
        destCoord = vec2(
                    .5 + .5 * destCoord.x,
                    .5 - .5 * destCoord.y);

        lowp vec4 fill_color = texture2D(colorSource, destCoord);

        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, fill_color, fill_color.a);

        lowp vec4 marks_color = texture2D(filledMarksSource, qt_TexCoord0);
        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, marks_color, marks_color.a * fill_color.a);
    }
}



240 and 320 degrees relative to what coordinate system?  Cartesian coordinates start with 0 to the east and increase counter-clockwise.  Compass coordinates start with 0 to the north and increase clockwise.

The red area looks like 210 to -30.  It can't be 240; 225 would point directly towards the lower left-hand corner.

You don't need a shader for this; you can use something like this instead: https://gist.github.com/0smr/839bd3a176ed934b68378550153e4a82.

@TimRoberts Thanks for the angle input, but still not achieved the expectation.

@smr thanks for sharing the inputs, but with use of shader I am still unable to achieve the expectation. Is there any example that uses circular gauge from qml and helps me to achieve the desired expectation. I can't use QtQuickTemplates as it is not supported by project so, the image I shared is reference of the expectation I want to acheive.

There is no need to use QtQuick.Templates; it is there to prevent Dial from recursing. Also, as far as I can tell, the example includes a gauge shape that uses a dashed border to create it. Try running the example I sent and changing its properties to understand it better.

To simplify the math, I will make the following assumptions:

All angular units are given in degrees
0 degrees is in the middle position of the speedometer (pointing up)
positive angles are in clockwise direction
negative angles are in a counter-clockwise direction
the smallest position of the speedometer is at -135 degrees
the largest position of the speedometer is at 135 degrees
this gives a sweep angle of 270 degrees for the speedometer

For drawing a speedometer needle ontop of a speedometer background, we can do this with two Images and use the rotation property directly on the needle.
Image {
    source: "speed-bk.png"
    /* RedArc { } */
    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "speed-needle.png"
        rotation: slider.value
    }
}
Slider { id: slider; y: 400; from: -135; to: 135 }

The following additional consideration is needed to convert from angles to (x, y) coordinates:

Trigonometry functions are in radians (so need to multiple PI/180)
Trigonometry functions are counter-clockwise by default.
In graphics positive y goes down the page, whereas in trigonometry positive y goes up (so we need to invert y)
The middle position of the needle corresponds to 90 degrees or PI/2

This yields the following formula for mapping speedometer polar coordinates to graphic (x, y) coordinates:
function polar(cx, cy, r, a) {
    return Qt.point(cx + r * Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - a * Math.PI / 180),
                    cy - r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - a * Math.PI / 180));
}

To implement a RedArc, we can use Shape, ShapePath, and PathArc with some cos/sin trigonometry to calculate the start/end points of the arc.
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Page {
    Image {
        source: "speed-bk.svg"
        RedArc { startAngle: -135; endAngle: slider.value }
        Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "speed-needle.svg"
            rotation: slider.value
        }
    }
    Slider { id: slider; y: 400; from: -135; to: 135 }
}

// RedArc.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Shape {
    width: 320
    height: 320
    property real radius: 105 
    property double startAngle: -135
    property double endAngle: 135
    property point start: polar(width/2, height/2, radius, startAngle)
    property point end: polar(width/2, height/2, radius, endAngle)
    ShapePath {
        capStyle: ShapePath.FlatCap
        startX: start.x; startY: start.y
        strokeColor: "red"
        strokeWidth: 50
        fillColor: "transparent"
        PathArc {
            radiusX: radius; radiusY: radius
            x: end.x; y: end.y
            useLargeArc: (endAngle - startAngle) >= 180
        }
    }
    function polar(cx, cy, r, a) {
        return Qt.point(cx + r * Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - a * Math.PI / 180),
                        cy - r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - a * Math.PI / 180));
    }
}

// speed-bk.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="320" height="320" fill="black" />
<circle cx="160" cy="160" r="130" fill="#444" />
<circle cx="160" cy="160" r="140" stroke="gray" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
<circle cx="160" cy="160" r="80" fill="black" />
</svg>

// speed-needle.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
<path stroke="transparent" fill="white" d="M 160 180 l -10 -20 l 10 -120 l 10 120 z"/>
</svg>


You can Try it Online!

I think what OP needs is the red arc, which should start from 0 and continue to the needle position.

Thanks @smr, I updated the answer based on your comment.
